# how to detect when browserify is being run?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I have a library that I want to use in both client side and server side. However, because `request` is not compatible with browserify, when compiling using browserify, I need to use a different library called `browser-request`

```
if (inNodejsRuntime) {
  var request = require('request');
} else if (isBrowserifyRuntime) {
  var request = require('browser-request');
}
```

How do I go about detecting when browserifying is running vs when it is inside node

Comment: just user superagent instead. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are just doing a simple module swap with compatible APIs you should use the [browser field](https://gist.github.com/defunctzombie/4339901) in package.json. So for your example, just do

```
var request = require('request')
```

like before and then in the package.json put:

```
{
  "browser": {
    "request": "browser-request"
  }
}
```

This way in the browser you will get browser-request instead of request when you `require('request')`.

What you *shouldn't* do is require both modules with a runtime check for the presence of `window` or some similar property. This is because you will get browser-request AND request bundled into your frontend code, even if you only actually use browser-request, resulting in a needlessly inflated file size.

Comment: Thanks @substack this is a better solution

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer is correct. But if you got here by googling 'detect browserify' and want the more general answer, browserify automatically transforms the node-provided global `process`. You can use:

```
process.browser
```

which will be `true` in the browser, `undefined` in node.

Comment: THANK YOU. Way too hard to find this.

Comment: Just a comment: Googling "detect browserify" got me back here in the first link (:

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  var request = require('request');
} else {
  var request = require('browser-request');
}
```

Superagent is also looking like a very good alternative!

Comment: As substack has pointed out, this will include both modules in the browserified code.